# st_intersect() not working in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis, spatial-index, spatial-query

i am using postgresql version : 
"PostgreSQL 9.3.1 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2), 64-bit"

i have created 2 tables A and B with point and polygon as a data type.
now i want to know whether point is inside the polygon or not.
for this i am trying to use ST_Intersect(A.point_LatLong , B.polygon_abc);
my query is :

```
SELECT A.id 
FROM A, B 
WHERE A.name = 'callifornia' 
AND ST_Intersect(A.point_LatLong , B.polygon_abc);
```

here `point_latLong` and `polygon_abc` are column name having datatype point and polygon in table A and B.

but this query gives an error :

> ERROR:  function st_intersect(point, polygon) does not exist
>   LINE 3: WHERE city.city_name = 'callifornia' AND ST_intersect(city.c...
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add 
>   explicit type casts.

---

How can I solve this problem? I even not be able to use any other spatial method in postgresql like st_contains() etc let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: `st_intersect()` is a PostGIS function, it sounds as if you did not install PostGIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to mix PostgreSQL's built-in (limited, but useful) geometric types with PostGIS functions. It sounds like you didn't install PostGIS, either. You've also typo'd the function name, it's `ST_Intersects` not `ST_Intersect`.

First, if you want to use PostGIS, make sure it's installed and then:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Next, you'll probably find that you can't actually call `ST_Intersects` with a `point` and a `polygon`. PostGIS works with its own `geometry` type. It has some converters for the PostgreSQL internal types, but they're only limited. So calling PostGIS functions with primitive geometric types can result in errors like:

```
postgres=# SELECT ST_Intersects( polygon( box(point(0,0), point(10,10)) ), point(5,5) );
ERROR:  function st_intersects(polygon, point) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_Intersects( polygon( box(point(0,0), point(10,10))...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

You'll often have to convert them to PostGIS's own `geometry` type. PostGIS provides some explicit casts for this for most types, e.g.:

```
postgres=# SELECT ST_Intersects(
    polygon( box(point(0,0), point(10,10)) )::geometry,
    point(5,5)::geometry 
);
 st_intersects 
---------------
 t
(1 row)
```

So in your query, that'd be:

```
ST_Intersects(A.point_LatLong::geometry , B.polygon_abc::geometry);
```

Comment: thank you Craig ringer 

now i have installed postgis, and after all the settings. now the query for st_intersects() is works fine for me.